# MVC with IIS 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've read a couple of posts on this issue but still can't seem to get MVC working on IIS 6. I've mapped .mvc to aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS but get a 404 when I browse to my mapped URL which looks like this

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("action", "api.mvc/{controller}/{action}", new {action = "Index"});
```

I then browse to //localhost/Web.Site/api.mvc/Users/List but get a 404 returned

same happens for

//localhost/Web.Site/api.mvc/Users/

I have a UsersController with List and Index that both returns a ViewAction

Is there anything else I need to do? Or have I missed something

cheers

also.............

I should point out that my redirect my default page in the website is working

eg my default code behind has

```
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

so the default "/" request does get correctly routed via this in the global.asax.cs

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("default", "", new {controller="Home", action = "Index" });
```

not sure if that helps anyone

Comment: Shouldn't it be "{controller}.mvc/{action}" ?

Comment: You said "yes its checked" - it should be **unchecked**?

Comment: from my understanding, it shouldn't matter. I tried it anyway but still getting 404's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting your default.aspx page and make sure you have this in your web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: added this to web.config and still same problem. Starting to think local environment is the issue.

Comment: I'll give you this even though it wasn't quite right. As I said I added that and still same problem. But when I added the entire god-awful-mess that gets generated when you create a MVC project and it works. I need to now go through it cull all the stuff I don't need.

cheers

Comment: Also note - despite the title of this Question - this had nothing to do with IIS 6

Answer (score 3):

Have you unchecked the "Verify that file exists" box on the extension mapping?